# Apply Gradient to more than one element inside an SVG Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am attempting to create an arrow that looks like this using SVG elements:

[image]

This is my attempt:

[image]

As you can see the gradient gets applied to both the **rect & the polygon** in my SVG. **Is there a way to replicate the gradient effect in the top image in my SVG?**

Maybe theres a CSS way to do this? Maybe I HAVE to use a **path or single polygon** element to create the arrow instead of a **rect** & **polygon**?

```
<svg width="424" height="100">
    <defs>
        <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255); stop-opacity:0" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(13,20,93);  stop-opacity:1" />
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>

    <rect x="0" y="25" rx="0" ry="0" width="212" height="50" fill="url(#grad1)"> </rect>
    <polygon points="212,0 212,100 424,50" fill="url(#grad1)"></polygon>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used two gradients to attempt to recreate what you were trying to do.  You can adjust the center of the gradient to align with the edges of the shapes:

```
<svg width="424" height="100">
    <defs>
        <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="100%" cy="50%" r="100%" fx="100%" fy="50%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255); stop-opacity:0" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(13,20,93);  stop-opacity:1" />
        </radialGradient>
        <radialGradient id="grad2" cx="0%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="0%" fy="50%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255); stop-opacity:0" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(13,20,93);  stop-opacity:1" />
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="25" rx="0" ry="0" width="212" height="50" fill="url(#grad1)"> </rect>
    <polygon points="212,0 212,100 424,50" fill="url(#grad2)"></polygon>
</svg>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cxW5U/)

Is there something wrong with a [single polygon](http://jsfiddle.net/BFvCL/1/) though?

```
<svg width="424" height="100">
    <defs>
        <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255); stop-opacity:0" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(13,20,93);  stop-opacity:1" />
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>

    <polygon points="212,0 212,25 0,25 0,75, 212,75 212,100 424,50" fill="url(#grad1)"></polygon>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6):

you can "make" a single path from two shapes by grouping them then apply the gradient to the group

```
<svg
 xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 version="1.1"
 width="424"
 height="100"
 id="svg2996">
 <defs>
 <radialGradient cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5" fx="0.5" fy="0.5" id="grad1">
  <stop style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:0" offset="0" />
  <stop style="stop-color:#0d145d;stop-opacity:1" offset="1" />
 </radialGradient>
 <radialGradient cx="212" cy="50" r="212" fx="212" fy="50" id="radialGradient3809" xlink:href="#grad1"
 gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
 gradientTransform="matrix(1,0,0,0.23584906,0,38.207547)" />
 </defs>
 <g style="fill:url(#radialGradient3809);fill-opacity:1">
  <rect width="212" height="50" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="25" />
  <polygon points="424,50 212,0 212,100 " />
 </g>
</svg>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMPMGQ)